# Is there a simple way to copy system settings from an EOL install to a new version?

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, settings

Here's my scenario:

I'm currently running Mint 12 as my open source development platform.  Currently, I'm running it as a VM through VirtualBox.  Since 12 is near it's end of life, and because running it as a VM isn't as efficient as I originally thought, the plan is to ditch it completely, then dual boot with Mint 14.

With that in mind, is there a way for me to transfer my settings from 12 to 14?  Not just packages (which, in my case, is just a matter of me grabbing things from dotdeb), but various server settings and program settings as well?

Put another way, is there anything can I automate or pre-package?  Are there any built-in ghosting tools or anything that could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have direct answer to your question other than backing up the whole `/etc` directory.

However, you should consider upgrading to new release. The following link is a tutorial for Mint upgrade: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2

With VirtualBox, you can make a snapshot before the upgrade. If things turn out bad, just roll back, no harm done.

You really don't need ghost in your situation. Just make a copy of the Mint vhd file if you later decide to run both side by side.